# GridView layout differing from Win8.1 to Win10

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-10

I am working on migrating a Windows 8.1 application to Windows 10 universal application, and I am getting a different look in my `GridView`.

In Windows 8.1, it behaves correctly and shows two rows (or more, height dependent):
[image: Windows 8.1 screenshot]

However, in Windows 10, regardless of the height, I only get one row:
[image: Windows 10 screenshot]

There is clearly enough space for the `GridView` to wrap to two rows, but no matter the height, it remains one row. Both use the same XAML definition:

```
<GridView Name="MyGridView"
          Margin="0,50,0,0"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AppPages}">
    ....
</GridView>
```

I have tried different `ItemsPanel` variations in the Windows 10 application, but I either get 1 row horizontal layout, or 1 column vertical layout. Is there a new property in Windows 10 or something that I need to set in order to allow the `GridView` to display multiple rows when height allows?

**EDIT**

The described behavior is just using the default `GridView` setup. I have tried the following as well:

```
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

with both `Vertical` orientation and `Horizontal`. But the layout of both the Windows 8.1 app and Windows 10 app are not specifying anything, just the `GridView` and its `ItemTemplate`. Here is the entire XAML for the `GridView`:

```
        <GridView x:Name="MainGridView"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AppPages}"
                  SelectionMode="None">
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                    <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="GridViewItemClick" TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Width="200"
                            Height="200"
                            BorderBrush="White"
                            BorderThickness="2">
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Width="150"
                                   Height="150"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}" />
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontSize="12"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=PageName}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </GridView>
```

Comment: Did you modify the template style of `GridView`? It looks that you change the `ItemsWrapGrid` of a `GridView` to the `ItemsStackPanel` of a `ListView` to me...You can create a new project and try `GridView`, it works well as it is in windows 8.1 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see what you tried is using `VariableSizedWrapGrid` as `ItemPanel`, as I said, by default it uses `ItemsWrapGrid` as `ItemPanel` both in an UWP app and Win8.1 app, you can tested it in a blank uwp app or a blank windows 8.1 app.

Just tested your code in both apps, when using `VariableSizedWrapGrid` as `ItemPanel`, `GridView` controls layout differing from Win8.1 to Win10 as they are in your pictures.

So I guess you probably apply a style using `VariableSizedWrapGrid` for your `GridView` somewhere in your code, for example when the `x:Key` property of a style is not be defined, this style can be applied to all the target-type controls in your page.

Usually we use `VariableSizedWrapGrid` if each tile/cell is variable size based on content. But from your picture, I think each item of your `GridView` has the same size.

So in this case, you can just modify the style like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewStyle1" TargetType="GridView">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

And apply this style specially to your `GridView` like this:

```
<GridView x:Name="MainGridView"
          Style="{StaticResource GridViewStyle1}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AppPages}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          SelectionMode="None">
```

Comment: I tried it as you mentioned with the `Orientation="Horizontal"` and it looked the same as it did without setting the `ItemsPanel` at all. However, just setting the `ItemsPanel` to `ItemsWrapGrid` like this: `<ItemsWrapGrid />` without specifying any attributes, it behaves as desired. Thanks.